# Subir una imagen con PHP

Tags: php

Como puedo subir una imagen a una carpeta local y cuando yo le de enviar en la siguiente página se muestre esa imagen. O simplemente que yo le de seleccionar archivo y en la siguiente página se muestre.

ES CON PHP, todo de manera local, no lo tengo que subir a un servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<label>Imagen
<input type="file" name="imagen"/>
</label>
<input type="submit"/>
```

Y en otro archivo de php, que es cuando se le da enviar me debe de salir esa imagen

```
$imagen = $_POST["imagen"];
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar la función `move_uploaded_file`.

Los archivos subidos al servidor, los puedes ver en la variable `$_FILES`

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/home/user/imagenes_subidas/imagen.png");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php